# How to hide the field in javascript in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
  $(".cross-reference-section-value-id").text(id);
  $(".cross-reference-section-value").text(to_s);
  $(".cross-reference-section-value").css('display', 'inline');
  $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");
  $(".cross-reference-clear-img").removeData([id, to_s]);
};
```

By this javascript, i bring the id and the string and stored into the label field in my html page. Now, I hide the id by the css attribute. I am just to displaying the string. I added a image of clear symbol next to the string. When i click that image, it should clear the both id and string fields and hide the image icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be much easier not to hide an `id`, just to store it in another place instead. For example:

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
    $("#cross-reference-section-value").data('id', id);
                                       .text(to_s);
                                       .css('display', 'inline');
    $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");
};
```

To access this property just use the same [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
var id = $("#cross-reference-section-value").data('id');
```

Comment: in the same field i have a button with the class name of .cross-reference-clear-img When we click this image i want to clear the field and make the id and string to the default state. is it possible?

Comment: Well, cleaning up the text is trivial (`.text('')`), and removing data is doubly so: `.removeData('id')` ([doc page](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/)). If you were talking about restoring the original line (that was removed with `.text(to_s)`, you can store (and restore) that line with `.data` as well.

Comment: First, you're trying to removeData from the wrong element (not the one you'd attached it to), so it won't work in any case. Second, to do something on click you need to register another function (that will clear both text and data) as clear-img click handler. Finally, it's not quite welcome here trying to squeeze several questions into a single one.

Answer (score 2):

Also, a small optimisation: you can concatenate the jQuery functions for speed

```
$("#cross-reference-section-value")
  .data('id', id);
  .text(to_s);
  .css('display', 'inline');
```

Even further, save the $("#cross-reference-section-value") in a variable:

```
var my_div = $("#cross-reference-section-value")
my_div
  .data('id', id);
  .text(to_s);
  .css('display', 'inline');
```

Comment: $('.cross-reference-clear-img).on('click', function(){ $("#cross-reference-section-value").text('') }